# AWSのAPI Gatewayを用いてURLに日本語（エンコード）が含まれるリクエストをGETメソッドで実装したい

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

AWSのAPI GatewayトLambdaを使ってAPIを作っています。
API GatewayでGETを用いているのですが、リクエストにUTF-8でエンコードされた日本語が含まれます。
これを受け取ってLambda関数に受け渡すためには、統合リクエストのテンプレートなどの設定をどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

```
event={
"key1":"値１",
"key2"："値2"
}
```

また、レスポンスにも日本語が含まれますがどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

```
response={
"res1":"値A",
"res2"："値B"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

以下の記事に記載されている内容をご確認ください。
現在の質問内容だと何をしたいのかが不明で、その達成したい内容によって回答が変わるかと思います。一旦ご確認いただいた上で再度質問していただくと適切な回答がつくかもしれません。
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pass-api-gateway-rest-api-parameters/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html

一応行間を読んで回答してみると、Lambda 側では event.queryStringParameters や event.multiValueQueryStringParameters でクエリパラメータを取得できます、が回答になるかもしれません。